# Custom error pages based on path/URL in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, http-status-code-404, global-asax

I have some pages in `/panel/` directory and some in `/website/` directory. I need two different 404 pages for these pages based on their path, because these directories have different `master pages`.

when I use `customErrors` in `web.config` file, it redirects all pages to one 404 page so it's useless for me.

How can I handle it? Can I handle it in `global.asax` or `master pages` or what?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create smaller `web.config` on those locations with the settings you want to override, or on the root web.config you specify the multiple `customErrors` settings inside `location` tags.

You don't need to change any code for this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to handle errors in the Global.asax file:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { Exception exc = Server.GetLastError(); 
if (exc is HttpUnhandledException) 
{ // Pass the error on to the error page.
 Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.aspx?handler=Application_Error%20-%20Global.asax", true); } }
```

Check out this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling) for more info